# Automatically adding new objects to a public static ArrayList not working

Tags: arraylist

I am trying to get newly made instances to be added to an ArrayList so could print out all the members. I tried the solution found below..

[Automatically adding every Class object constructed into an ArrayList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16119102/automatically-adding-every-class-object-constructed-into-an-arraylist)

However, I got an error below..
"The method add(Integer) in the type ArrayList is not applicable for the arguments (Bike)"

Here is the code. Any ideas? Still new to Java, so forgive me for basic question. Any help is great, thank you.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Bike {
    
    private int cadence;
    private int gear;
    private int speed;
    private int id;
    private static int numberOfBicycles = 0;
    public static ArrayList<Integer> bikeIds = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        
    public Bike(int startCadence, int startSpeed, int startGear){
        gear = startGear;
        cadence = startCadence;
        speed = startSpeed;

        // increment number of Bicycles
        // and assign ID number
        id = ++numberOfBicycles;
        bikeIds.add(this);
    }
```

I tried the suggestions in the IDE but didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

This code has a problem in two aspects:

1. ```
   public static ArrayList<Integer> bikeIds = new ArrayList<Integer>();
   ```
2. ```
   bikeIds.add(this);
   ```

The `ArrayList`'s type is `Integer`, but you put `this` in your `add` method.
The type of `this` is `Bike`.
So, their types aren't same.

Comment: Thank you and I get it. I thought since the ArrayList will be holding the number assigned to each bike (which is int) that I should make it that. But it's actually holding Bike objets (which contains the int variable, which is passed). I just tried using Bike as the type and it worked. Thank you!